# How to update specific row using checkbox?

Tags: vb.net

This is what I've tried. This works for checkbox value only and all displayed data will be updated.

```
 Public Sub updateDGV()



    Dim id As String
    Dim cb As String
    Dim time As String
    Dim str As String
    Dim mycon As New SqlConnection(ConString)
    Try
        mycon.Open()
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
            row.Cells(22).Value = Date.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt")
            id = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString
            cb = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString
            time = row.Cells(22).Value.ToString
            str = "UPDATE GuardMonitoring SET EmploymentStatus =@EmpStat, 
           ModifiedBy =@ModifiedBy, ModifyDate =@ModifyDate WHERE 
            (Employee_Id =@EmpId)"


            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(str, mycon)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = id
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpStat", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cb
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModifiedBy", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserPass.txtfull2.Text
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModifyDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = time
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Next
        mycon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        showmsg.ForeColor = Color.LightCoral
        showmsg.Text = "Rows not found!"
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Expected output: update only when changing the specific value of checkbox.

Comment: It should be fairly obvious that if you want to do something for a row only IF it is checked then you need an `If` statement in there somewhere.  This is why I tell people to work out the logic they want to implement before they start writing any code to implement it.  If you had done that then there would have to be some check in that logic for whether the row was checked or not, so you would have to implement that logic in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to update only the row that have checkboxes turned ON?
If so, it can be determined by the value of the checkbox cell.

For example, like this.

```
 Public Sub updateDGV()



    Dim id As String
    Dim cb As String
    Dim time As String
    Dim str As String
    Dim mycon As New SqlConnection(ConString)
    Try
        mycon.Open()
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
            If Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells("your checkbox column name").Value) Then
                row.Cells(22).Value = Date.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt")
                id = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString
                cb = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString
                time = row.Cells(22).Value.ToString
                str = "UPDATE GuardMonitoring SET EmploymentStatus =@EmpStat, 
               ModifiedBy =@ModifiedBy, ModifyDate =@ModifyDate WHERE 
                (Employee_Id =@EmpId)"


                Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(str, mycon)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = id
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpStat", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cb
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModifiedBy", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserPass.txtfull2.Text
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModifyDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = time
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If

        Next
        mycon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        showmsg.ForeColor = Color.LightCoral
        showmsg.Text = "Rows not found!"
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! i forgot i put FalseValue and TrueValue in cb column.